# Formatting standard measurments

Tags: узус

My team is working on a software for parsing Russian text / documents. I am completely new to Russian language hence posting this question. My questions are:

1. How do we represent standard metric system in Russian? For example, how do we write 100 meters or 100 litres or 100 km or 100 seconds etc.
2. How do we represent months and year and dates? For example, "10 January", "10th January" or "10th Jan, 2016" or 12/31/2015 etc?
3. How do we represent email? For example, if I need to write rbhatt@gmail.com.
4. How do we represent numbers (numeric system 0-9)? For example, 1234.

I hope for a native Russian these would be a cake walk questions to answer. I would be greatly thankful for any other info related to Russian language that would help me in my job. Thanks in advance and apologies for writing this in English.

Comment: Do you need to associate nouns with your numbers? In English, this is relatively straightforward: 1 [object], zero-or-many [objects]. However you should be aware that in Russian this is much more complicated, it is not simply "singular" and "plural". Also, as in any other language, you might need to deal with cases where numbers are spelled out as words (e.g., "three" rather than "3"), including fractions (e.g., "three and a half").

Comment: please, tend to as one question per post.

Answer (score 5):

1. There are standard Russian signatures using cyrillic letters, i.e. "**km**" --> "**км**" etc. See [Russian Wiki on SI units](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86#.D0.95.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B_.D0.A1.D0.98).
2. "European" style rather than "american". See [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).
3. As is.
4. Screenshot from Windows control panel:
   [image]

Comment: You can use Microsoft's localization style guide for Russian. It should satisfy your issues. You can download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/StyleGuides.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> How do we represent standard metric system in Russian? For example,
>   how do we write 100 meters or 100 litres or 100 km or 100 seconds etc.

- 100 meters - 100 метров
- 100 litres - 100 литров
- 100 km - 100 км
- 100 seconds - 100 секунд (или 1 минута 40 секунд)

> How do we represent months and year and dates? For example, "10
>   January", "10th January" or "10th Jan, 2016" or 12/31/2015 etc?

10 января
10.1 or 10.01 (first day then month)
10.I (rarely - day as a Western number, month as a Latin number)

10 января 2016
10 января 2016 года
10.1.2016
10/1/2016
10.01.2016
10/01/2016
10.I.2016
Some use "-" instead of ".", but always remeber: day should be before month.

> How do we represent email? For example, if I need to write rbhatt@gmail.com.

Just like this: rbhatt@gmail.com . Email is language-independent.  The character "@" is pronunced собака, the character "." is pronunced точка.

> How do we represent numbers (numeric system 0-9)? For example, 1234.

Just like this: 1234.  If there is a fractional part, it is separated by "," , but some computer programmers use "." .

Answer (score 0):

my suggest is that you would better hire a translator. the subject is too complex to make notes about it here.

however, if your tasks do not involve anything complex involving translations you can use help of various opensource projects relating to internationalization. such as gnu i18n (try google search), they already have made all the necessary work for such sort of tasks and they have nice documentation regarding subject.

> How do we represent standard metric system in Russian? For example,
>   how do we write 100 meters or 100 litres or 100 km or 100 seconds etc.

measurement units are written as in any other country using metric system

> How do we represent months and year and dates? For example, "10
>   January", "10th January" or "10th Jan, 2016" or 12/31/2015 etc?

there are pretty common standards for writing dates in exUSSR countries

> How do we represent email? For example, if I need to write rbhatt@gmail.com.

we do not write email in any specific form

> How do we represent numbers (numeric system 0-9)? For example, 1234.

numbers are also written pretty much the same way as everywhere else in the world (well, in most of it)